# to compare each element of the array and subtract the larger number from the smaller one? or is there any possible way to do it

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop, if-statement

I am  writing a perl code which subtracts the number from array B to A ie. B-A but the problem is if array B element is greater it is not able to minus the vice versa.

```
      @dataset1= ("2", "1", "1", "1");
      @dataset2= ("3","3","2","0");
       print "dat1 @dataset1\n";
       print "dat2 @dataset2\n";


      for(my $i=0;$i<=$#dataset1;$i++){

       $minus=$dataset2[$i]-$dataset1[$i];
       print " $minus\n";

      }
```

the output is :

```
 dat1 2 1 1 1
 dat2 3 3 2 0
 this 1
 this 2
 this 1
 this -1
```

But the way I want my output to be is:

```
 dat1 2 1 1 1
 dat2 3 3 2 0
 this 1
 this 2
 this 1
 this 1
```

Please suggest something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use absolute value.

```
$minus=abs($dataset2[$i]-$dataset1[$i]);
```

Comment: if i have to match the two numbers in the two dataset how to skip that index if both the number is 0. the code I am using is   if ($count_f_dataset2[$i]||$count_f_dataset1[$i]==0) {
next;

} but this doesn't seems to work.

Comment: what is $count_f_dataset2?

Comment: Count_f_dataset1 is an array is this-> AAAAAAA  0 
AAAAAAT  0
AAAAAAG  0
AAAAAAC  1 and count_f_dataset2 is another array AAAAAAA  0 
AAAAAAT         3 
AAAAAAG  5 
AAAAAAC  0  so if the string AAAAAAA value is 0 in both the arrays it should skip that string.